# How to represent one special related record

Tags: database-design, relational-database, normalization

I have two tables, `project` and `photo`. `photo` has `ID`,`projectID`,`path` : each `project` has multiple `photo`s.

Now one of these `photo`s is the one that has to be displayed. The question is how to represent this in the database.

Earlier, I used descending order of `ID` numbers and chose the latest one, but that failed and caused problems. Now I am not sure which way to go :

- Create a new table `projectPhotoDisplayed` that holds `project`.`ID` and `photo`.`ID`(those that are to be displayed only) numbers.
  The bad : too much work, as well as replicating the information that `photo` table already has (`photo`s associated with `project`s ).
- Create a new binary field in the `photo` table. If true, then display, else not.
  The bad : Structurally does not prevent multiple `photo`s being marked to display. I want radio button behavior
- Create a new field in the `project` table that stores the `photoID` of the `photo` to be displayed.
  The bad : Does not ensure that the particular `photoID` is actually linked to this `project`. Also does this information belong here?
- Any approach with foreign keys so that referential integrity is maintained..?

Using PHP and MySQL InnoDB database, though I'm sure it won't matter.

Which is the best way to store this info?

Answer (score 2):

All the three ways are viable solutions, but I would avoid the first one and the third one because of redundant information which could get "out of sync". There could be a photoID stored as foreign key of a photo which belongs - or is moved to - a different project.

> Create a new binary field in the photo table.

You surely meant a *boolean* field, not a *binary field*. This would be my favorite option. To make sure there will be at maximum one photo to be displayed, you may add "before update" and "before insert" triggers to your DB, counting the numbers of rows where your "display" column has the value "true" and throwing an error if there would be more than one. [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html) you find an example how to use "before insert" triggers for verifying constraints.

Comment: Thanks! Would you advise an `enum` field if I needed to store 3 states (thumbnail, displayed, none)? And yes, I meant boolean.

Comment: @MilindR: Probably yes, sounds like the canonical solution.

Comment: I updated my question.... Is there no possibility of using foreign keys to enforce everything? I don't mind creating new columns.. Just felt this approach isn't clean enough.